# Ionic 4 and ngx-charts - Problem with responsiveness in ion-grid inside an ion-slide

Tags: responsive, ionic4, ngx-charts, ion-slides, ion-grid

I'm having problems with the responsiveness of ngx-Charts inside an "ion-slide", or more precise, a ngx-Chart within an "ion-grid" which resides in an "ion-slide".

For the chart to be responsive I found two rules. One says, that you should not use the "view" parameter inside the ngx-Chart.
The second one says, that the surrounding / parent tag should have a size. If both are true, the chart should adapt to the size of the parent.

I even made it work (be responsive) inside a grid - a grid on a "usual" page, but I'm not able to make it work (be responsive) inside a grid within a slide.

Please see my example-project on GitHub https://github.com/Joey73/ionic-ngx-charts.git (pages: Treemap and Treemap in Slide).

treemap-in-slide.page.html:

```
...
<ion-content>
  <ion-slides pager="true" [options]="slideOpts">

    <!-- The chart in this slide works / is responsive -->
    <ion-slide class="chart-wrapper">
      <ngx-charts-tree-map
        [scheme]="colorScheme"
        [results]="treemapData"
        (select)="onSelect($event)">
      </ngx-charts-tree-map>
    </ion-slide>

    <!-- The chart in this slide is not responsive - it's inside a grid -->
    <ion-slide>
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <h1>TreeMap in ion-grid</h1>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="12">
            <div class="chart-wrapper">
              <ngx-charts-tree-map
                [scheme]="colorScheme"
                [results]="treemapData"
                (select)="onSelect($event)">
              </ngx-charts-tree-map>    
            </div>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>    
</ion-content>
```

treemap-in-slide.page.scss

```
.chart-wrapper {
    max-height: 35vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Outside ion-slide the charts (even if they are in an ion-grid) are responsive.

What can I do to make a ngx-chart responsive which is inside an ion-grid which resides in an ion-slide?

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution myself.

html:

```
...
<ion-slide>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <h1>TreeMap in ion-grid</h1>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="12">
        <div>
          <ngx-charts-tree-map
            (window:resize)="onResize($event)"
            [scheme]="colorScheme"
            [results]="treemapData"
            (select)="onSelect($event)"
            [view]="view">
          </ngx-charts-tree-map>    
        </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-slide>
...
```

ts:

```
...
export class TreemapInSlidePage {
  title = 'ngx Treemap in Slider with Ionic 4';

  treemapData: any[];

  slideOpts = {
    initialSlide: 0,
    speed: 400
  };

  view: any[] = [700, 400];

  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#5AA454', '#A10A28', '#C7B42C', '#AAAAAA', '#4381D1', '#65ECE4']
  };

  constructor() {
    if (innerWidth > 992) {
      this.view = [innerWidth - 300, 400];
    } else {
      this.view = [innerWidth, 400];
    }
    Object.assign(this, { treemapData });
  }

  onResize(event) {
    if (event.target.innerWidth > 992) {
      this.view = [event.target.innerWidth - 300, 400];
    } else {
      this.view = [event.target.innerWidth, 400];
    }
  }

  onSelect(event: Event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

global.scss:

```
...
.split-pane-visible >.split-pane-side {
    min-width: 300px!important;
    max-width: 300px!important;
}
```